# Calculate and display multiple integer inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery and is trying to create a page where people can order tickets. I have two different ticket types with a select input for each. I would like to calculate and display the number of total tickets selected.

Here are my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("select").change(function() {
     var numberOfTickets = 0;
     $("select.tickets-selection").each(function() {
       numberOfTickets = numberOfTickets + parseInt($(this).val());
     })
   $(".ticket-subtotal p.amount").val(numberOfTickets);
  });
});
```

For the HTML please check my JDFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mckeene/975Lsvdn/3/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Also include what is not working about the code you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of `val`:

```
$(".ticket-subtotal p.amount").html(numberOfTickets);
```

`val` is only for inputs.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/975Lsvdn/4/)